# FAIL - Application at context path [/geoserver] could not be started

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, windows-11

I just installed in Windows 11 the product Cartoview which is open-source GIS Web app and includes GeoNode, GeoServer, PostGIS, and the web server Apache Tomcat. After successfully installed the package, all apps run ok besides GeoServer which I can't run it from the Tomcat manager where I get the message:

> FAIL - Application at context path [/geoserver] could not be started

I tried to install in the Tomcat environment a second fresh downloaded GeoServer 2.19.2, but same thing happens, both GeoServers won't start.

This is geoserver log:

```
    2022-02-02 14:26:34,466 WARN [geoserver.config] - Error reading resource URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:240)
    at org.geoserver.config.SpringResourceAdaptor.relative(SpringResourceAdaptor.java:34)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerPropertyOverrideConfigurer.setLocations(GeoServerPropertyOverrideConfigurer.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
2022-02-02 14:26:36,697 WARN [ejb.Ejb3Configuration] - hibernate.connection.autocommit = false break the EJB3 specification
2022-02-02 14:26:36,820 WARN [dialect.H2Dialect] - The 1.1.119 version of H2 implements temporary table creation such that it commits current transaction; multi-table, bulk hql/jpaql will not work properly
2022-02-02 14:26:37,241 WARN [dialect.H2Dialect] - The 1.1.119 version of H2 implements temporary table creation such that it commits current transaction; multi-table, bulk hql/jpaql will not work properly
2022-02-02 14:26:37,484 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [Rule]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,612 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [RuleLimits]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,614 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [usergroup]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,617 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [GSUser]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,623 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [GFUser]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,626 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [gsinstance]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:37,634 WARN [cache.EhCacheProvider] - Could not find configuration [LayerDetails]; using defaults.
2022-02-02 14:26:43,933 WARN [platform.resource] - There is code leaving resource input streams open, locks around them might not be cleared! Add -Dgs.lock.trace=true to your JVM options to get a full stack trace of the code that acquired the input stream
2022-02-02 14:26:59,017 ERROR [support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.importer.ImporterContextCleaner.run(ImporterContextCleaner.java:39)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2022-02-02 14:27:01,102 WARN [auth.GeoFenceAuthenticationProvider] - INIT FROM CONFIG
2022-09-08 16:31:45,403 WARN [geoserver.config] - Error reading resource URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Cartoview/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.19-20211215.021821-355.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:240)
    at org.geoserver.config.SpringResourceAdaptor.relative(SpringResourceAdaptor.java:34)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerPropertyOverrideConfigurer.setLocations(GeoServerPropertyOverrideConfigurer.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

Comment: Check both the Tomcat and GeoServer logs to see what went wrong, then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. Also we need to know which versions of Java and Tomcat you have installed - GeoServer won't work with Java 17 and Tomcat 10

Comment: Yes, i added geoserver logs (partly)

Comment: this looks to be the same problem as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440901/docker-geoserver-geofence-issue

Comment: i tried to delete the geofence plugin but i still get same error