# Docker GeoServer GeoFence Issue

Tags: geoserver, docker

I am trying to test the Geofence Plugin using the official [Docker project](https://github.com/geoserver/docker) of GeoServer. Unfortunately when running

`docker run -it --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="authkey,geofence-server,geofence" -p 8080:8080 docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.21.1`

the startup fails and I can see this error in the logs

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.65/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.21.1.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.65/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-geofence-server-2.21.1.jar!/geofence-default-override.properties`

I also tested it using a mounted volume, but that didn't help either:

`docker run -it -v //c/Users/username/Docker/geoserver:/opt/geoserver/data --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="authkey,geofence,geofence-server" -p 8080:8080 docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.21.1`

I am on Windows using Docker with WSL2. Testing it only with the authkey plugin works fine. Any ideas how to make it work on Windows?

**UPDATE:**
So I tried to run it locally without Docker on Ubuntu WSL2 using the [Linux Binary](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux.html). And adding geofence and geofence-server by unzipping the binaries into the webapps folder:

`/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib`

Same result like using Docker. I see the above Error and at `http://localhost:8080/geoserver` I see a broken WebCache site but not the geoserver interface:
[image: Broken Geoserver UI]

So I guess it is not an issue of the Docker version but an overall issue with the Geofence Plugin(s). Anything I am missing?

Comment: There was a Docker/GeoServer/GeoFence question posted just yesterday that is now gone. If that was your Question, you need to know that deleting and reposting is a way to spur the SE anti-spam automation into blocking your account.

Comment: Not intentionally. I started writing my question yesterday but I didn't submit. Maybe I miss-clicked and submitted. But I can't find anything in my history, so I doubt it. But thanks for making me aware of the anti-spam automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with this over the weekend I finally found this [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg35765.html) that guided me to this [issue](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence/issues/102).

Long story short: Somehow GeoWebCache and GeoFence interfere so Geoserver landing page is still reachable via `http://localhost:8000/geoserver/web` and not `http://localhost:8000/geoserver`. This can also be fixed by some settings - see links.

Comment: Meanwhile in my case i cant even start geoserver from tomcat, it won't start and when i read geoserver logs it says same error like above.